# Design pattern for persisting model and view across routes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

Let's say I have a search form at `/search` with a `QueryView` representing the search form.  When the user submits a query, I would like to route to `/results` and add a `ResultView` for the results, keeping the `QueryView` in case the user wants to do a new search.

Then, if the user navigates directly to `/results`, I have to create both the `QueryView` and the `ResultsView` in the route function.  The problem is that I'd like the behavior in the `/search` and `/results` routes to be the same, but have to remember to make any changes in both places.

An alternative is to trigger the route for `/results` when the user submits, which will destroy the existing `QueryView` and create a new `QueryView` and `ResultView`.  This works, but destroying and recreating the `QueryView` causes some annoyances in my case.

Are there standard design patterns to persist views across routes, without having code to create the view in two places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up writing a [ViewManager class](https://github.com/elplatt/backbone-viewmanager.js) to handle persisting views across routes. Example usage:

```
// On load
var FooView = Backbone.View.extend({ ... });
var BarView = Backbone.View.extend({ ... });
var vm = new ViewManager({selector: ".content");

// On route
var foo = vm.getView(FooView, {}, true);
vm.showViews([foo]);

// On another route
var foo = vm.getView(FooView, {}, true);
var bar = vm.getView(BarView, {}, true);
vm.showViews([foo, bar]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the shared behavior in to a method of router, then have both routes call that method.

To cache your `QueryView` you can simply make it a property of your `Router`.  Inside both your `/search` and `/results` routes, simply do something like:

```
this.queryView = this.queryView || new QueryView();
this.queryView.doWhatever();
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question. Even if both call the same function, in one case a QueryView already exists, and in another, the QueryView needs to be created.